# Android: Dynamically add Images using Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm having a lot of trouble adding images to my android project. The research I've done so far hasn't shown much about using a Canvas.

My main function:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

Player player = new Player(this);

    main_page = new LinearLayout(this);
    main_page = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    main_page.addView(player);
```

And my Player file:

```
public class Player extends ImageView
{
Bitmap icon;
Rect src = null;
Rect position= null;
Paint paint = null;

public Player(Context context) 
{
    super(context);

    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
    position = new Rect(0,0, 100, 100);
    src = new Rect(0,0, icon.getWidth(),icon.getHeight());
    invalidate();
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(icon, src, position, paint);
}
}
```

Thank you to whoever can tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: What errors the log show?

Comment: No errors, but when I step through the debugger it ends up throwing an exception in the activity class. ..... try {
                upIntent.prepareToLeaveProcess();
                return ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().navigateUpTo(mToken, upIntent,
                        resultCode, resultData);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                return false;
            }